# How to remotely disable MobiUCare from sending "SIM card change" SMSes?

Tags: sms, mobiucare, anti-theft

My mother just changed her SIM card. I forgot to disable MobiUCare and I'm about a thousand of kilometers away from the phone.

**I keep receiving an SMS:**

> SIM card changed. Plz check phone if lost or stolen" with SIM ID and Gmail ID.

I found that MobiUCare supports lots of SMS commands to remotely track/wipe phone. Doesn't it have any to **defuse** the anti-theft system? I mean, I expected the change of SIM card, the new one is legitimate.

<sup>Actually one SMS can be considered enough instead of an half-hourly report that drains credit</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer: No

Based on the currently available information at their [support FAQ page](http://www.mobiucare.com/support/faq), **no**, you cannot disable the *"SIM card change notification"* feature with remove SMS control:

> ### How can I control device via SMS
>
> Configuration
>   1) Set a password and enable SMS command option using "Preference" menu of the app
>   2) Send SMS commands
>
> Locate phone : ## locate password
>   Siren : ## siren password
>   Lock screen : ## lock password screenlockpassword
>   Factory reset : ## wipe password
>   Reset and format SD : ## wipeall password
>   Toggle GPS : ## gps password
>   Toggle WIFI : ## wifi password
>   Toggle Bluetooth : ## bluetooth password

---

### What can you do:

You can let the phone owner know how to access the app and from there, pressing "preferences", it can access the *"Allow Notify via SMS"* enable/disable checkbox:

[image: Feature Enable / Disable Screen]